# Table design using composite sort keys and item collections

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm building a DynamoDB table named "Uploads" representing files in S3 alongside meta data like category, tags and author.

My access patterns are:

- Get upload by id
- Get uploads by user id
- Get uploads by tag
- Get uploads by category

Schema:

```
{
    pk: "S"
    sk: "S",
    s3url: "S",
    category: "S",
    title: "S',
    description: "S",
    tags: "SS"
}
```

Sample:

```
{
    s3url: "https://..",
    category: 'fashion',
    title: "Summer Wear',
    description: "Fresh in from Italy",
    tags: ['fashion', 'summer', 'light', 'on-sale', 'staff-pick']
}
```

In order to write efficient queries and **completely** avoid scan operations, I'm organising the table into item collections relying on composite sort keys to support my queries. I'm not aiming at building a "Single Table Design", but maintain item collections in a handful of tables.

Example table containing two upload items (upload#1 + upload#2):

| pk | sk | attributes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Upload | Upload#1 | id, s3Url, title, description, author, tags |
| Upload | Category#fashion | id |
| Upload | Tag#outdoors | id |
| Upload | User#9999 | id=1 |
| Upload | Upload#2 | id, s3Url, title, description, author, tags |
| Upload | Category#fashion. | id |
| Upload | Tag#summer | id |
| Upload | User#9999 | id=2 |

I find the learning curve is steep and I'm unsure if I'm going in the right direction.
Knowing my use case and access patterns, are you able help me in the right direction?

I was trying to avoid creating lot of GSIs due to cost and complexity.

Comment: pk=upload and sk=tag#outdoors won't work because pk+sk must be unique. I'd recommend watching/reading modeling discussions by Alex DeBrie and Rick Houlihan (plenty of free content available, [example](https://youtu.be/Q6-qWdsa8a4?list=PLlmC4sSMCVJwRGHMAb4vz8FbCmfNC_5_Z&t=1136)).

Comment: @jarmod There is no requirement for pk to be unique as long as the combination of pk + sk is unique. That's referred to as a compound primary key. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/

Comment: You're repeating exactly what I said ;-) Yes, pk+sk must be unique. If I understand your table above, you have an item with pk=Upload and sk=Tag#outdoors for ID 1. What happens when another upload happens, say upload ID 25, that is also tagged with outdoors? You could have an sk of Tag#outdoors#id, which *would* be unique.